# WPF button press on Windows 7 mulit-touch

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-7, touchscreen, multi-touch

I am developing a WPF kiosk like client that will be deployed on an HP TouchSmart Windows 7 machine with multi-touch enabled.  My problem is that with Windows 7 multi-touch, the application does not recognize a finger 'tap' as a button press event, and therefore the button press Trigger to change color is never fired.

The Windows 7 animation for the touch usually displays, and the button click event fires fine.  It is only the XAML define style for the 'IsPressed' event that does not function as intended on a finger tap.  It does eventually work if enough pressure is applied with a finger and/or you roll or press like you would do for a fingerprint.  Is there a workaround for to make a 'tap' fire a press/click event?

```
<Trigger Property="AreAnyTouchesOver" Value="true">
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PressedOff}" />
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PressedOn}" />
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>

<Trigger Property="AreAnyTouchesDirectlyOver" Value="true">
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PressedOff}" />
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PressedOn}" />
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: For now we have decided to forgo the eye-candy to push the release out the door, maybe I will have time to come back to it later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not clear on what you want t do.

Some explanation on your issue:

In touch IsPressed is only triggered when your contact is held down over the element and the movement threshold is passed to create a "press" (That is why you see it if you press the finger down and slide it slightly)

As soon as the contact comes up IsPressed = false.

When you "tap" a button you are in essence doing a mouse click. This is why events fires as expected.

So what exactly are you trying to do? You want to fire an storyboard animation when a button is "held down" ("IsPressed") or when a button is clicked (tapped).

These are two different situations, also note that often times desktop metaphors do not translate well to the touch environment. You may want to rethink how you are giving visual feedback to the user.

I think the easiest answer for what you want to is Trigger on "TouchDown" if I understand your questions correctly.

UPDATE:

This should work for a TouchDown trigger

```
<Button Content="Touch Down Example" Height="20" Width="20">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.TouchDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    ....
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

**NOTE**: I don't have a touch screen in front of me so there could be errors but it looks correct.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - I'm having difficulty communicating what I want.  You are correct, I want a Trigger on 'TouchDown', how do I do this?  Some background: the kiosk client is being developed on a standard Gvision Touch screen (no multi-touch) - therefore touch/press/click works the same. The app is being deployed to multi-touch enabled PC, hence my communication issues.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Updated my answer to include example

Comment: Tried your solution, I'm still not seeing the result I expect. I'm wondering if Windows 7 is interpreting the quick tap as an accidental touch. Also tried suggestion from http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/527886/touchdown-does-not-trigger-until-the-touch-moves

Comment: Does the device you are testing support the Window 7 Touch API correctly? If it does then it should be triggering the TouchDown event on the button correctly. It is highly likely that your hardware is not Win7 compliant (I have seem many vendors claim they are but don't actually support the API correctly).

Comment: I am facing this issue as well. I am using IsPressed trigger for my button. However, it doesn't seem to have any button effect when press/tap with finger but it works when using mouse click.

Answer (score 6):

Simply set the `Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled` attached property to `False` for the button.  This will cause the button's `IsPressed` property to be set/cleared in response to a touch as well as a mouse click.

From the documentation for the [UIElement.TouchDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.touchdown.aspx):

> To cause the PreviewTouchDown and TouchDown events to occur as soon as a finger touches the screen, set the Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled attached property to false for this element.

For example, you could use a setter in your button style to make sure the property is set to false:

```
<Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="False"/>
```

I found this question while trying to find a way to make my button reliably animate for both mouse clicks and touch events.  The accepted answer sent me down what seems to be the wrong path: Synchronizing storyboards with touch up/down events. Using the `IsPressed` property trigger for both has proven to be simple and reliable.  Hopefully this saves someone else from making a similar mistake.

Comment: Can you link me to something that explains how a static property like that can be set to a value only for one specific element? Why wouldn't it be a global change?

Answer (score 2):

For touch development, I would recommend using the [Microsoft® Surface® Toolkit for Windows Touch Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=801907A7-B2DD-4E63-9FF3-8A2E63932A74) in your project, and using the surface controls included, since they handle touch events properly, and a multitude of use cases, such as a user pressing a button with 2 fingers, and lifting them one at a time. Only the last "lift" or TouchUp event should trigger a Click event.

All of the surface controls are subclasses of the Windows controls, so SurfaceListBox subclasses ListBox, SurfaceButton subclasses Button, etc. This way, all your styles and templates will still work with these controls.

In your case, you will want to use the SurfaceButton control. Simply add a reference to the toolkit assemblies, and in your outer element (, , etc), add a reference to the surface namespace, such as

```
xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
```

and then add the surface controls from that namespace, such as

```
<s:SurfaceButton x:Name="button1" Click="OnButtonClick" />
```

Comment: Agree completely. However, if the problem the author is seeing is due to the touch screen vendor not properly supporting Windows 7 Touch API (as it seems might be the case) then the Surface Toolkit won't help much there. Regardless, if beta software is an option for this project then definitely use the Surface Toolkit

Comment: @Foovanadil - missed this comment when you first posted it, sorry. The reason I mentioned it explicitly is that I am presently working with a device in the HP Touchsmart product line, and this was the cause of my problem as well. Unhandled touch events *should* get promoted to mouse events, but in reality, a number of things could be swallowing those events without further notice.

Comment: Thanks Hugo, I will try out the Surface API when I have a chance.  For now we went back to a non multi-touch enabled touchscreen.